# Not able to get textbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hi im trying to do something with some input but the input(except municipality) is showing to be empty string. so building will show to be empty even though id fill the textbox. no console errors.

```js
$('#editAddress').submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var mun = $("#municipalities option:selected").text();
  var city = $("#city").val();
  var street  = $("#street").val();
  var building = $("#building").val();
  var floor = $("#floor").val();
  var addr = $("#address").val();
  alert("bldg: "+building);
  editAddr( mun,city,street,building,floor,addr);
 });
```

```html
   <form id="editAddress" action = '' method = 'post'>
                            <select id ="municipalities" class ="form_select" placeholder="Municipality">
                                <option>Select Municipality</option>
                                <option>Beirut</option>
                                <option>Mlikh</option>
                                <option>Haret Hreik</option>
                                <option>Haret Saida</option>
                                <option>Jounieh</option>
                                <option>Baalbeck</option>
                                <option>Hermel</option>
                                <option>Tebnine</option>
                                <option>Jwaya</option>
                            </select>
                            <input type="text"     name="city"         id="city"           class="form_input" placeholder="City"/>
                            <input type="text"     name="street"       id="street"         class="form_input" placeholder="Street"/>
                            <input type="text"     name="building"     id="building"       class="form_input" placeholder="Building"/>
                            <input type="text"     name="floor"        id="floor"          class="form_input" placeholder="Floor"/>
                            <textarea              name="address"      id="address"        class="form_input" placeholder="Address Notes"></textarea>
                            <input type="submit" name="register" class="form_submit" id="editAddr" value="Edit Address" />
                        </form>
```

Comment: I don't see any problem at all.
Your issue might be on your EditAddr function call. 

`alert("bldg: "+ mun + " " + city + " " + street+ " " + building + " " +  floor + " " +  addr);`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery already handles that:

```
var mun = $("#municipalities").val()
```

Everything else is in order:

```js
    $(function() {
        $('#editAddress').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var mun = $("#municipalities option:selected").text();
            var city = $("#city").val();
            var street  = $("#street").val();
            var building = $("#building").val();
            var floor = $("#floor").val();
            var addr = $("#address").val();
           console.log(mun, city, street, building, floor, addr);
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="editAddress" action = '' method = 'post'>
    <select id ="municipalities" class ="form_select" placeholder="Municipality">
        <option>Select Municipality</option>
        <option>Beirut</option>
        <option>Mlikh</option>
        <option>Haret Hreik</option>
        <option>Haret Saida</option>
        <option>Jounieh</option>
        <option>Baalbeck</option>
        <option>Hermel</option>
        <option>Tebnine</option>
        <option>Jwaya</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text"     name="city"         id="city"           class="form_input" placeholder="City"/>
    <input type="text"     name="street"       id="street"         class="form_input" placeholder="Street"/>
    <input type="text"     name="building"     id="building"       class="form_input" placeholder="Building"/>
    <input type="text"     name="floor"        id="floor"          class="form_input" placeholder="Floor"/>
    <textarea              name="address"      id="address"        class="form_input" placeholder="Address Notes"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="register" class="form_submit" id="editAddr" value="Edit Address" />
</form>
```

Comment: municipalities is already taking the value from the textbox its the other vars that are always empty form some reason :/

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm. Seems to work for me. Be sure that you include the jQuery library, as in below code example.

Go ahead and type something in the building field and it alerts with that data.

Is something else wrong that I did not notice? If so, please leave a comment with that information.

```js
$('#editAddress').submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var mun = $("#municipalities option:selected").text();
  var city = $("#city").val();
  var street  = $("#street").val();
  var building = $("#building").val();
  var floor = $("#floor").val();
  var addr = $("#address").val();
  alert("bldg: "+building);
  editAddr( mun,city,street,building,floor,addr);
 });
function editAddr(){
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="editAddress" action = '' method = 'post'>
                            <select id ="municipalities" class ="form_select" placeholder="Municipality">
                                <option>Select Municipality</option>
                                <option>Beirut</option>
                                <option>Mlikh</option>
                                <option>Haret Hreik</option>
                                <option>Haret Saida</option>
                                <option>Jounieh</option>
                                <option>Baalbeck</option>
                                <option>Hermel</option>
                                <option>Tebnine</option>
                                <option>Jwaya</option>
                            </select>
                            <input type="text"     name="city"         id="city"           class="form_input" placeholder="City"/>
                            <input type="text"     name="street"       id="street"         class="form_input" placeholder="Street"/>
                            <input type="text"     name="building"     id="building"       class="form_input" placeholder="Building"/>
                            <input type="text"     name="floor"        id="floor"          class="form_input" placeholder="Floor"/>
                            <textarea              name="address"      id="address"        class="form_input" placeholder="Address Notes"></textarea>
                            <input type="submit" name="register" class="form_submit" id="editAddr" value="Edit Address" />
                        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps

1)Try to run the code by removing `e.preventDefault();`

2)remove form input class from input box and add  form-control

```
<input type="text"  name="city" id="city"  class="form-control" placeholder="City"/>
<input type="text"  name="street" id="street" class="form-control" placeholder="Street"/>
<input type="text"  name="building" id="building" class="form-control" placeholder="Building"/>
<input type="text"  name="floor"  id="floor"  class="form-control" placeholder="Floor"/>
<textarea  name="address"  id="address"  class="form-control" placeholder="Address Notes"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="register" class="form_submit" id="editAddr" value="Edit Address" />
```

Answer (score -1):

```
document.getElementById('address').value
```